# kong api gateway keep url address plugin

Tags: api-gateway, kong

I just installed kong api gateway and konga UI on standalone ec2.
I configured a simple service with route to out site.
everything is working great!

my question is if there is any plugin for kong that can keep the original browser url after the redirect?
For example:

client send request to `www.koko.example.com` and kong redirect him to `www.fofo.example.com`.
what happened now is that the user see in the browser url address line the [www.fofo.example.com](http://www.fofo.example.com) and i want to keep the `www.koko.example.com` address there..

Is there any option to do it?

Comment: Have you really configured Kong to redirect ? Classic configuration is to have Kong as a proxy

Comment: yes, i only created simple service and simple route by host.
am i missing something?

Comment: So you don't set up a [redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) Kong will proxify the query and you want to transform the answer to translate the url.

Comment: @yoyo got any solution to preserve caller route url than service url ?

Comment: @AbdulRazakAK , unfortunately still no...

Answer (score 0):

You have a kong module

https://github.com/dsteinkopf/kong-response-string-replace

body_replace_patterns will be:

```
www.fofo.example.com###www.koko.example.com
```

There is also an nginx module to do that
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

A kong article with other solution:
https://medium.com/@peterkimnyc/url-rewriting-in-kong-b887d65ca072